Label week 1 to week 4/5 on every Friday of that month in PostgreSQL
I have a large list of dates, and I want to make a weekly report for 1 month, and the weekly report always starts on Friday. I am having difficulty creating a query to label week 1 to week 4/5 of the month.
I have made a query like this:
SELECT
rank() over(PARTITION by EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM log_barang.log_date::date) in (6)) "week",
EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM log_barang.log_date::date) dayy,
to_char(log_barang.log_date::date, 'TMDay') as dayname,
log_barang.log_date::date as tanggal
FROM
log_barang
WHERE
EXTRACT(MONTH from log_barang.log_date)=4 AND
EXTRACT(YEAR from log_barang.log_date)=2024 
GROUP BY
dayy, tanggal
ORDER BY
tanggal asc

but the result is always 1 and cannot be divided into weeks 1 to 4/5.
what I want is like this:



week
dayy
dayname
tanggal




1
1
Monday
2024-04-01


1
2
Tuesday
2024-04-02


1
3
Wednesday
2024-04-03


1
4
Thursday
2024-04-04


1
5
Friday
2024-04-05


2
6
Saturday
2024-04-06


2
7
Sunday
2024-04-07


2
1
Monday
2024-04-08


2
2
Tuesday
2024-04-09




You can use dense_rank() and shift Saturdays and Sundays to their following week.
demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT dense_rank()OVER w1 AS "week",
       EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM log_barang.log_date::date) AS dayy,
       to_char(log_barang.log_date::date, 'TMDay') AS dayname,
       log_barang.log_date::date AS tanggal
FROM  log_barang
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM log_barang.log_date)=4 
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM log_barang.log_date)=2024 
GROUP BY dayy, tanggal
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM log_barang.log_date::date)
                      +(EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM log_barang.log_date::date) in (6,7))::int)
ORDER BY tanggal asc;

If the ISODOW is either 6 or 7, the resulting boolean is true, which cast to an integer is a 1. Adding that to the week number will push Saturdays and Sundays into next week.



week
dayy
dayname
tanggal




1
1
Monday
2024-04-01


1
2
Tuesday
2024-04-02


1
3
Wednesday
2024-04-03


1
4
Thursday
2024-04-04


1
5
Friday
2024-04-05


2
6
Saturday
2024-04-06


2
7
Sunday
2024-04-07


2
1
Monday
2024-04-08


2
2
Tuesday
2024-04-09


2
3
Wednesday
2024-04-10


2
4
Thursday
2024-04-11


2
5
Friday
2024-04-12


3
6
Saturday
2024-04-13


3
7
Sunday
2024-04-14


3
1
Monday
2024-04-15


3
2
Tuesday
2024-04-16


3
3
Wednesday
2024-04-17


3
4
Thursday
2024-04-18


3
5
Friday
2024-04-19


4
6
Saturday
2024-04-20


4
7
Sunday
2024-04-21


4
1
Monday
2024-04-22


4
2
Tuesday
2024-04-23


4
3
Wednesday
2024-04-24


4
4
Thursday
2024-04-25


4
5
Friday
2024-04-26


5
6
Saturday
2024-04-27


5
7
Sunday
2024-04-28


5
1
Monday
2024-04-29


5
2
Tuesday
2024-04-30



